# android "state_pressed" works only in second attempt

Tags: android

I've one menu button and a motion class for a longer state_pressed state (0,5 sec.). So long all works fine, but one problem occurs :

I've to press first time on my button, state_pressed doesn't work at this first time then on the second attempt my code works correctly and state_pressed works with 0,5 seconds duration.

How can I make it that it works on the first press? I think tehre is a problem with the hover.xml file and in combination with the setBackgroundDrawable?

Thanks all in advance for ur help!

**This is my hover.XML drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_focused="false" 
      android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/buttonstyle_pressed" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonstyle" />
```

**And this is my java code**

```
    Button menubutton_start;

    menubutton_start = (Button) FindViewById(R.id.menustart);


 menubutton_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {     

  menubutton_start.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hover));


   final Handler handler = new Handler();            

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

              public void run() {

               Intent myIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
               GameActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                    }

                }, 500);  // end of Handler new Runnable()


    }  // end of OnClick()


});  // end of setOnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pressed state will happen automatically if you apply that style to the button.

You shouldn't have to manually set the pressed state in your code at all.

Comment: I've updated my eclipse environment to 4.0.3 and this error occurs again. (at 2.2 it was working) :-( thx for any help!

Comment: so now finally solved the problem. it was my background_img, which was overlayed over the normal button, so pressed_state state couldn't check the ressource at the first press.